# Why does the intrinsicContentSize of my NSTextField not change as I enter characters?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nstextfield

I am trying to achieve a custom `NSTextField` that resizes horizontally (without wrapping text) as text is added to the `NSTextField`. The Content Compression Resistance Priority property should be able to assist in the above (I have set this to 1000) but it is actually having no effect.

That gets me to the title of my question: I call `intrinsicContentSize` within the overridden `keyUp()` method of my custom `NSTextField` but it shows that `intrinsicContentSize` is not changing - I am pretty sure that for content Compression Resistance to work it would need to have a changing `intrinsicContentSize`.

## EDIT

As Ken Thomas's points out below, `NSTextField` does not have an intrinsic width so I shouldn't have expected it to change as I entered more characters. Below is the code I have added to make it change though:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize:NSSize{
    return NSMakeSize(self.attributedStringValue.size.width + 20, 20)
}

override func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    super.textDidChange(notification)
    self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

Comment: What is custom about your `NSTextField` subclass? Unless you've attempted to alter the default behavior, editable text fields don't have an intrinsic width. That is, `textField.intrinsicContentSize.width == NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric`. That's because when a text field is editable, its content is not intrinsic, it's extrinsic. If you have attempted to alter it, you need to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Your comment is presumably the answer to the question I asked. It doesn't change because it's `NSViewNoIntrinsicMetric` (If you turn your comment into an answer I can accept it). This also accords with my further experience. I have now overridden the `intrinsicContentSize` property and am invalidating it when the text changes...what is eluding me is how to get the contentCompressionResistance to kick in and dynamically increase my `NSTextField` width. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the constraints on your text field?

Comment: self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true <Swift>

Comment: Well, that's a problem. When the autoresizing mask is translated into constraints, the resulting constraints fully determine the frame of the view. At best, the intrinsic size could create a conflict when the priority is 1000, but I'm not sure if it actually does. I doubt that the intrinsic size is translated into implicit constraints for a view with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` enabled. Setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is more or less opting out of auto layout for that view.

Comment: @KenThomases thanks. I presume that setting the frame of the NSTextField would be even worse then as AutoLayout is then definitely off. I guess I'll have to use full AutoLayout here then. Was trying to avoid it because I'm going to be creating and destroying this textField in different places many times and the frame approach seemed easier and to have less overhead.

Comment: If `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is enabled, then setting the frame is entirely appropriate. Indeed, that's the basis for the constraints that get generated — the last frame that was set explicitly plus the autoresizing mask.

Comment: @KenThomases but the constraints generated from the frame will then all have full priority and so the `contentCompressionResistance` won't kick in.

Comment: Right. You can either keep `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on and set the frame (including its size) manually, or you can disable it and use auto layout "for real". My previous comment was just saying that setting the frame is not "even worse then as AutoLayout is then definitely off". First, setting the frame doesn't turn auto layout off. If auto layout is on (in the sense of `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` being off), setting the frame is simply undone on the next layout pass. But if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is on, then setting the frame is normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you've attempted to alter the default behavior, editable text fields don't have an intrinsic width. That is, `textField.intrinsicContentSize.width == NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric`. That's because when a text field is editable, its content is not intrinsic, it's extrinsic.